# Cardinality with specialization in enhanced entity-relationship diagrams

Tags: database-design, erd

I'm currently taking an introduction course to databases and I've come across a problem not described in the textbook.

I'm wondering about the use of cardinality with the use of specialization in enhanced entity-relationship (EER) diagrams.

The case is that I wish to have e.g. a **Team** which has to have one and only one leader (a designated role). However the **Team** also consist of other roles. In total each **Person** can only have one role in the team.

I can't seem to figure out how to draw this up from the description of EER diagrams in my textbook. Am I, by the standardization, allowed to draw min-max pair for the arrows in specializations? Or is there another way to make conditional relationships.